# Custom font does not work in react provided create react app

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, create-react-app

I downloaded the custom font `Rounded Mgen+ 1c` into my react project.

But somehow, it doesn't work correctly.

### What I did

- Downloaded the font into `public/fonts/` and `src/`.
- Added `import code` into the `src/index.css` like below.

```
:

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rounded Mgen+';
  src: url(./rounded-mgenplus-1c-bold.ttf) format('ttf');
}

:
```